# Can't catch exception thrown by IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, ironpython

I run a Python script in which I declare some variables and execute some operations when some events occur. This script is generated dynamically based on operations stored in the database, so there can be some variables that have not been defined or syntax errors and an exception is thrown by IronPython. Example:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine();
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope = py.CreateScope();

for (int i = 0; i < gatilhos.Count; i++)
{
     pyScript = "import clr\n";
     pyScript += VlrCampos; // Python variable declarations.
     pyScript += "result = " + gatilhos[i].Regra + "\n";
     try
     {
          py.Execute(pyScript, scope);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
}
```

At some point `gatilhos[i].Regra` will, for example, contain:

> abc + a

with **abc** not defined in that scope, so `IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException` is thrown but execution breaks and the exception is not handled.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean that the execution breaks in the Visual Studio Debugger?

Comment: @dynamoid Yes, exactly

Comment: This is a normal behavior. You can disable this particular exception in the Exception Settings, so the Debugger won't break anymore.

Comment: But what if I actually want to handle those exceptions?

Comment: With the code you provided, all exceptions will be handled (actually not really all, native SEH exceptions won't, but that doesn't matter for now). On my system, the `UnboundNameException` is caught and printed in the console.

Comment: hmm.. Any idea of what might be happening?